# Why i can't animate or move the character in blender pose mode?

Tags: animation, rigging, pose-mode

Please help me to solve my problem. I'm a software developer not an artist so I'm really having a hard time to learn animation and blender(even though i should be able to learn fast using the software but it's not. LOL)  and i need help.

I'm following this tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LM50gJJOrQ

I'm almost in the last part. I am now in this part **05:17**

This is what i have in my blender.

[image]

i already clicked the **GENERATE RIG BUTTON**

[image]

i already clicked the **With Automatic Weights**

[image]

i also followed this part

[image]

but i don't know how to follow this part(in the tutorial).
What is the shortcut used for the timestamp **05:17**

[image]

Because i don't know the shortcut used i tried to change this to **pose mode**

But still i can't make the character move or animate like the one in the tutorial. Please help me. Thank you

This is the file.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/12OCHZDNLRFaFdM4gXfjMGzOoW2uNfzzR/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: hello, maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I think you parented your character to the metarig, not to the rig itself: aftert generating the rig you should hide the metarig and use the generated rig only. Going to pose mode is the correct way.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing as Josh. Rigify initially produces a rig that is only intended to be used for matching the shape of the armature to the shape of your mesh. That's the metarig. Once the metarig is in position, the new final rig is generated from it. However, the metarig sticks around. You can get rid of it or hide it. But don't use it any further with that same character. The generated rig is the one that needs to be bound to your mesh.

Comment: Good day everyone. I updated the question and i added the link for the file. Thank you